# Unable to execute lodash command using Java's ScriptEngineManager

Tags: java, lodash

I am attempting to run a lodash command using Java's Script Engine Manager. I've added the lodash-4.15.0.jar file to my classpath.

Here is my code:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("_.camelCase('TestTh@t Column'))");
```

my expected result is: testthtColumn however I see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "_" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:451)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:16)
Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "_" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1426)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
    ... 5 more
```

Due to my lack of experience with javascript in general I am not sure how to fix this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up performing this in Java in lieu of getting lodash to work. Though not a direct answer, this returns the same answer as lodash's camelCase method.

```
public String camelCaseHeaderName(String s) {
        String result = "";
        boolean firstElem = false;
        String[] words = s.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String[] finalWords = words[i].split("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+");
            for(int j = 0; j < finalWords.length; j++) {
                String tmp = finalWords[j].replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
                if(!firstElem) {
                    tmp = tmp.toLowerCase();
                    firstElem = true;
                } else {
                    tmp = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(tmp);
                }
                result = result.concat(tmp);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```